# ReTest bloc of tests in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have a list of tests to execute on robot framework where it has a block of tests that can be executed again if a specific test fails as the following flow explains, And i want to know if this is dowable with robot framework.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not doable. At least, not in a single test run, and not without a lot of work. Robot has no ability to re-run a test within a single test run. You would have to exec a second instance of robot where the output is sent to a separate output file, and then you would have to somehow merge the output files of the original test run and the second exec.

However, robot does support being able to give it the output.xml from a previous run so that it will re-run only the failed test cases. You can do that with the `--rerunfailed` command line option. See [Re-executing failed test cases](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#re-executing-failed-test-cases) in the robot framework user guide.